# React Native Fetch Function Clearing State

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I am brand new to React Native and trying something that may be way over my head. I am looking to to use the fetch command to pull in data and save it as a property of my state. Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch('http://swapi.co/api/people/')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseData => {
  this.setState({
    tweets: responseData.results
  });
  console.log(this.state.tweets)
})
.catch(error => {
  alert('Fetching and parsing data error ' + error);
})
.then(console.log(this.state.tweets));
}
```

The first `console.log()` outputs the correct array I am pulling, but the second `console.log()` displays null.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: you can also add some string to `console.log` to see what was called first. Ex. `console.log('after setting state', this.state.tweets)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous so checking state right after setting it will not work.

To see state after it's set - pass callback to set state as second argument.

```
this.setState({
    tweets: responseData.results
}, () => console.log(this.state.tweets));
```

`setState` calls also `render` method, so you can preview new state there.

Answer (score 0):

If you tag your console.log something like "first", "second", etc., you will see that your last console.log invokes firstly. So fixed that, you should wrap the last console.log with fat arrow or anonymous function. So it will be invoked in the order you want.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://swapi.co/api/people/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseData => {
    this.setState({
      tweets: responseData.results
    });
  console.log(this.state.tweets)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    alert('Fetching and parsing data error ' + error);
    })
  .then(()=>console.log(this.state.tweets)); // Here
}
```